# How to get results of each team laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, sorting, multidimensional-array, eloquent

i need to create standings for each league. Releationships:

Team model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'league_id', 'stadium'];

    public function league() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\League');
    }

    public function players() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Player');
    }

    public function matches() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Match');
    }
    
}
```

Match model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Team;

class Match extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['round', 'match_date'];
    protected $guarded = ['league_id', 'home_team_id', 'away_team_id'];  

    public function leagues() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\League');
    }

    public function homeTeam() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'home_team_id');
    }

    public function awayTeam() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'away_team_id');
    }

    public function score()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Score', 'match_id');
    }
}
```

created standings function, when fetch all teams of league.
Standings should have matches, wins, draws, loses. May someone could help, how to take that data?

```
 public function standings(League $league, Team $team) {
        $teams = Team::with('league')->where('league_id', $league->id)->get();
       
        //dd($team_matches);
        return view('admin.leagues.standings')->with('teams',$teams);
    }
```

Comment: How do you evaluate wins, draws and losses? Are these data stored on matches table or somewhere else?

Comment: Matches have releationship with scores (match_id, home_team_score, away_team_score)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get all data would be

```php
 public function standings(League $league, Team $team) {
    $teams = Team::where('league_id', $league->id)
        ->with([
            'league.matches.score' 
        ])
        ->get();
       
    //dd($team_matches);
    return view('admin.leagues.standings')->with('teams',$teams);
}
```

Then while rendering in the view you can have wins and losses calculated from the score.

Comment: getting this error, smth wrong: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'matches.team_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `matches` where `matches`.`team_id` in (1))

Comment: What is the foreign key on matches tables and which column it references on the teams table? You have already defined a `matches` relation on the **Team** model - which columns are you using for connecting the two

Comment: matches have (league_Id, home_team_id and away_team_id)

Comment: Then how have you defined matches as a relation on Team model with hasMany relation? Anyway you can access matches via league. See the updated answer.

Comment: thank you. But how to display all games for each team in view? may you have some sources where i can learn about that conditions in controller or smth like that. Thank you.

Comment: Now what are games? If you mean matches then either you need a relation between team and matches which can be done on home_team_id or you need to pull all leagues for the team and matches of the leagues